# Ionic framework: how to run on android tablet without the latest API version

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and Cordova. Trying to run a sample app and deploy it to my Nexus 7 android tablet. Already have android SDK installed and windows variables configured (already program native android), but still when I run

```
ionic run android
```

I get the error below

[image]

But I don't want to deploy to API level 22. Already changed "todo\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml" file to the following content

```
...
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
...
```

but that also didn't worked. Anybody have a clue on what is going on? Can this be an Ionic or Cordova bug?

Comment: It's not a bug...  Use target 22...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on this link:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/build-for-older-api-version/18972/2

I have to update the "todo\platforms\android\project.properties" file with the desired API level.